# inserting new values inside an array, inside the controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am taking the inputs `BlogTitle,BlogBody` and sending `$BlogData` to validation,,,

But how can i insert a new value i.e., BlogUrl which is generated inside the controller so that `$BlogData` will have those 3 values

```
$BlogData = Input::only('BlogTitle', 'BlogBody');
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$BlogData = Input::only('BlogTitle', 'BlogBody');

$BlogData['BlogUrl'] = 'http://whatever.com';
```